# Sass - Assign variable with another variable

Tags: sass

I have this variable:

```
$color_pr1: #d6ad3f;
```

Now, I'm using Gumby and it uses it's own settings sheet where the following is set:

```
$header-font-color: #55636b !default;
```

Is it possible to use `$color_pr1` instead? Like this?

```
$header-font-color: $color_pr1; ?
```

If now, am I thinking about this all wrong? 
I'd like to have my own set of colors etc and reuse those within my project.

Comment: Yeah you can do it. You should try before ask.

Comment: There's no issue in doing just that, try it and you'll see it works. But you should aim at keeping your code readable.

Comment: I did try.. It was the !default; bit behind the second assigned variable that was keeping Scout from compiling.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the docs:  http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_defaults_

> You can assign to variables if they aren’t already assigned by adding
>   the !default flag to the end of the value. This means that if the
>   variable has already been assigned to, it won’t be re-assigned, but if
>   it doesn’t have a value yet, it will be given one.

For example:

```
$content: "First content";
$content: "Second content?" !default;
$new_content: "First time reference" !default;

#main {
  content: $content;
  new-content: $new_content;
}
```

is compiled to:

```
#main {
  content: "First content";
  new-content: "First time reference"; }
```

Variables with null values are treated as unassigned by !default:

```
$content: null;
$content: "Non-null content" !default;

#main {
  content: $content;
}
```

is compiled to:

```
#main {
  content: "Non-null content"; }
```

Comment: Ah, it was the !default; that was bugging me. Thanx! :) Yes, I did try it before asking of course. I'm using ScoutApp for compiling, and it just gave me an error before.

Answer (score 2):

Use css `calc()` function:

```
$header-font-color: calc(#{$color_pr1});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define a map:

From the [Sass Documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables)

```
Users occasionally want to use interpolation to define a variable name based on another variable. Sass doesn’t allow this, because it makes it much harder to tell at a glance which variables are defined where. What you can do, though, is define a map from names to values that you can then access using variables.

SCSSSassCSS
SCSS SYNTAX
@use "sass:map";

$theme-colors: (
  "success": #28a745,
  "info": #17a2b8,
  "warning": #ffc107,
);

.alert {
  // Instead of $theme-color-#{warning}
  background-color: map.get($theme-colors, "warning");
}
```

Comment: I got a "Invalid CSS after" error and it turns out there is an error in the documentation, it is map-get and not map.get  ->  https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2890#issuecomment-616216159